# Make a footer appear after scrolling below 100% window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hard to explain in the title so i'll explain what I'm requesting. I currently have a content wrapper class which has a height of 100%. I would like this to reach the bottom of the window and then when a user scrolls down the footer will appear. However at the moment I believe the wrapper div is pushing the footer out of sight but I can't scroll down. Here's an image of what I can see so far https://gyazo.com/117100c3408956a85aa957bdce2b5b13

Eventually the wrapper div will be transparent but it's black for now to help see. The idea is that if I were to scroll down at this point a footer would emerge.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

HTML:

```
<body id="chesters">

    <img src="assets/home-bg.jpg" id="home-bg" alt="">

        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="burritos.html">BURRITOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img class="header-image" src="assets/Headerlogo1.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

    <div id="Page">

        <div id="content" class="wrapper">

        </div>      

        <div id="footer">
            <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet feugiat orci. Vestibulum volutpat iaculis erat non maximus. Nam dictum faucibus aliquam. Maecenas mollis suscipit purus sit amet mattis. Suspendisse vitae turpis lectus. Fusce at efficitur nunc, id congue libero. Donec efficitur lacus non orci ornare luctus.

Aenean id nulla eget diam finibus vehicula sed et dolor. Mauris et purus justo. Pellentesque vitae eros nec ante sodales eleifend ut convallis nulla. Cras diam massa, ornare eget venenatis ut, posuere ut tortor. Duis quis tristique quam. Fusce consequat enim nisl. Curabitur ornare eros a risus tincidunt, eget scelerisque lacus varius. Quisque sed dapibus justo. Etiam eleifend consectetur neque a rutrum. In ac eleifend elit. Vestibulum sagittis est vitae lacus ornare, eget accumsan nibh tincidunt. Vestibulum est turpis, suscipit in risus ac, imperdiet auctor urna. Sed non sem quam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

            </p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Page -->

    </body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#Page {
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 100px;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#home-bg {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

header {
    background-color: #1c1c1b;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
    font-size: 250%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #009641;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.header-image {
    align-content: center;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.scroll {
    height: 80px; 
    font-size: 180%;
}

.header-image-scroll {
    height: 80px;
}

nav {

}

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav li a {
    color: #009641;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #e2030e;
    text-decoration: underline #f3f3f3;
}

#content {
    background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: deeppink;
}
```

Comment: Provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `position: relative;` for css id `Page` :

```css
html, body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#Page {
    position: relative;
    top: 10vh;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#home-bg {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

header {
    background-color: #1c1c1b;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
    font-size: 250%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #009641;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.header-image {
    align-content: center;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.scroll {
    height: 80px; 
    font-size: 180%;
}

.header-image-scroll {
    height: 80px;
}

nav {

}

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav li a {
    color: #009641;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #e2030e;
    text-decoration: underline #f3f3f3;
}

#content {
    background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<body id="chesters">

    <img src="assets/home-bg.jpg" id="home-bg" alt="">

        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
                <li><a href="burritos.html">BURRITOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img class="header-image" src="assets/Headerlogo1.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

    <div id="Page">

        <div id="content" class="wrapper">

        </div>      

        <div id="footer">
            <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet feugiat orci. Vestibulum volutpat iaculis erat non maximus. Nam dictum faucibus aliquam. Maecenas mollis suscipit purus sit amet mattis. Suspendisse vitae turpis lectus. Fusce at efficitur nunc, id congue libero. Donec efficitur lacus non orci ornare luctus.

Aenean id nulla eget diam finibus vehicula sed et dolor. Mauris et purus justo. Pellentesque vitae eros nec ante sodales eleifend ut convallis nulla. Cras diam massa, ornare eget venenatis ut, posuere ut tortor. Duis quis tristique quam. Fusce consequat enim nisl. Curabitur ornare eros a risus tincidunt, eget scelerisque lacus varius. Quisque sed dapibus justo. Etiam eleifend consectetur neque a rutrum. In ac eleifend elit. Vestibulum sagittis est vitae lacus ornare, eget accumsan nibh tincidunt. Vestibulum est turpis, suscipit in risus ac, imperdiet auctor urna. Sed non sem quam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

            </p>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Page -->

    </body>
```

Comment: @webmaster Thank you very much sir, I had a feeling it would be something small I was doing wrong -.- All working fine now :)

Comment: Keep rollin @EthanBristow :)